# Clojure: why is aget so slow?

Tags: arrays, performance, clojure

In my thinking, clojure vectors have a slight performance hit compared to java arrays. As a result I thought that "conventional wisdom" was that for those performance-critical parts of your code, you'd be better off using java arrays.

My tests however suggest that this is not true:

```
Clojure 1.3.0
user=> (def x (vec (range 100000)))
#'user/x
user=> (def xa (int-array x))
#'user/xa
user=> (time  (loop [i 0 s 0] (if (< i 100000) (recur (inc i) (+ s (nth x i))) s)))
"Elapsed time: 16.551 msecs"
4999950000
user=> (time  (loop [i 0 s 0] (if (< i 100000) (recur (inc i) (+ s (aget xa i))) s)))
"Elapsed time: 1271.804 msecs"
4999950000
```

As you can see, the aget adds about 800% time to this addition. Both methods still are way slower than native java though:

```
public class Test {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    public static void main (String[] args) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        int[] x = new int[100000];                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        for (int i=0;i<100000;i++) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
            x[i]=i;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        long s=0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        long end, start = System.nanoTime();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        for (int i=0;i<100000;i++) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
            s+= x[i];                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        end = System.nanoTime();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        System.out.println((end-start)/1000000.0+" ms");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        System.out.println(s);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
}                              

> java Test
1.884 ms
4999950000
```

So, should my conclusion be that aget is 80 times slower than nth, and about 800 times slower than []-access in java?

Comment: A lot of work has gone into keeping you from having to make this kind of optimization :)

Comment: Posted a followup on strange aget optimisation behavior at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144937/strange-aget-optimisation-behavior

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect this is down to reflection and autoboxing of the primitive types by the aget function....

Luckily aget/aset have performant overloads for primitive arrays that avoid the reflection and just do a direct array[i] access (See [here](http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-Support%20for%20Java%20Primitives) and [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.3.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L2067)).

You just need to pass a type hint to pick up the right function.

```
(type xa)
[I    ; indicates array of primitive ints

; with type hint on array
;
(time (loop [i 0 s 0] 
        (if (< i 100000) (recur (inc i) 
          (+ s (aget ^ints xa i))) s))) 
"Elapsed time: 6.79 msecs"
4999950000

; without type hinting
;
(time (loop [i 0 s 0] 
        (if (< i 100000) (recur (inc i) 
          (+ s (aget xa i))) s)))
"Elapsed time: 1135.097 msecs"
4999950000
```

Comment: both cases are being auto-boxed

Comment: Thanks! With type hinting, my java array solution is now twice as fast as the clojure vector one. Still, it's 5 times as slow as native java, so I guess the "real" solution would be to factor out this part of the code into a plain java class, right?

Comment: @Claude - This was an interesting exercise comparing the relative performance of the two approaches, and thus a little artificial. However, had you question been "What's the best/quickest way to sum a sequence of 100,000 ints?" then a simple ``(reduce + xa)`` as proposed by NielsK is the clearly superior (and most idiomatic) approach. I'm assuming you need to do something a bit more than that and that's what's taken you down this road.

Answer (score 4):

it looks like reflection is washing out all your test's accuracy:

```
user> (set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
true
user> (def x (vec (range 100000)))
#'user/x
user>  (def xa (int-array x))
#'user/xa
user>  (time  (loop [i 0 s 0] (if (< i 100000) (recur (inc i) (+ s (nth x i))) s)))
NO_SOURCE_FILE:1 recur arg for primitive local: s is not matching primitive, had: Object, needed: long
Auto-boxing loop arg: s
"Elapsed time: 12.11893 msecs"
4999950000
user> (time  (loop [i 0 s 0] (if (< i 100000) (recur (inc i) (+ s (aget xa i))) s)))
Reflection warning, NO_SOURCE_FILE:1 - call to aget can't be resolved.
NO_SOURCE_FILE:1 recur arg for primitive local: s is not matching primitive, had: Object, needed: long
Auto-boxing loop arg: s
Reflection warning, NO_SOURCE_FILE:1 - call to aget can't be resolved.
"Elapsed time: 2689.865468 msecs"
4999950000
user>
```

the second one just happens to have more reflection in it.

When running this kind of benchmark be sure to run it many times to get the hotSpot compiler warmed up

```
user> (time  (loop [i 0 s 0] (if (< i 100000) (recur (inc i) (+ s (aget xa i))) (long s))))
"Elapsed time: 3135.651399 msecs"
4999950000
user> (time  (loop [i 0 s 0] (if (< i 100000) (recur (inc i) (+ (long s) (aget xa i))) (long s))))
"Elapsed time: 1014.218461 msecs"
4999950000
user> (time  (loop [i 0 s 0] (if (< i 100000) (recur (inc i) (+ (long s) (aget xa i))) (long s))))
"Elapsed time: 998.280869 msecs"
4999950000
user> (time  (loop [i 0 s 0] (if (< i 100000) (recur (inc i) (+ (long s) (aget xa i))) (long s))))
"Elapsed time: 970.17736 msecs"
4999950000
```

in this case a few runs dropped it down to 1/3 the original time (though reflection is still the main problem here)

if I warm them both up with dotimes the results improve a lot:

```
(dotimes [_ 1000]  (time  (loop [i 0 s 0] (if (< i 100000) (recur (inc i) (+ s (nth x  i))) s))))
"Elapsed time: 3.704714 msecs"

(dotimes [_ 1000] (time  (loop [i 0 s 0] (if (< i 100000) (recur (inc i) (+ (long s) (aget xa i))) (long s)))))
"Elapsed time: 936.03987 msecs"
```

Comment: https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium is good for benchmarking with JIT warmup etc.

Comment: Actually, this is the best answer to the actual question: why it's slow. Still the implied question - how to speed it up - is indeed through the use of type hint on the array. Thanks for the clarification though!

Answer (score 4):

Seems no type hints are needed at all, Clojure optimizes nicely out of the box.

When a polyadic function needs to be done over a collection, just use apply and the function. When you need a function applied to elements in a collection and the result stored in an accumulator, use reduce. In this case, both apply.

```
=> (def xa (into-array (range 100000)))
#'user/xa

=> (time (apply + xa))
"Elapsed time: 12.264753 msecs"
4999950000

=>(time (reduce + xa))
"Elapsed time: 2.735339 msecs"
4999950000
```

And even simpler evens out these differences as well, though slightly slower than the above best case:

```
=> (def xa (range 100000))
#'user/xa

=> (time (apply + xa))
"Elapsed time: 4.547634 msecs"
4999950000

=> (time (reduce + xa))
"Elapsed time: 4.506572 msecs"
```

Just try write the simplest code possible, and only if that's not fast enough, optimize.

Comment: In this case you're right, but obviously my real-life example is way more complicated than just adding stuff, and needs `aget`s from different arrays. Actually the differences in your first tests have to do with compiler optimizations, when you first run the reduce and then the apply, the apply is the faster one.

Comment: The tests were done repeatedly; apply stayed at ca 12 ms, reduce started out at ca 12s as well, but stabilized at ca 2.7 ms. Thats why tests with burn-in time are important on the JVM. I upvoted Sw1nn's answer, in case truly random access is needed. Often functional algorithms based on Clojure core functions can be applied, taking advantage of its internal optimisations, and advantages like laziness.