# clojure amap is very slow

Tags: arrays, performance, clojure

So I've been doing basic image processing in clojure (just converting rgb to grayscale), and I'm having serious issues with amap; namely, that I can't make it quick.

I've been able to get it down from 21000ms to about 8000ms with type hints, but that's about it. In contrast, normal map runs in about 400ms...

Is there anything else I can do to this to make it as fast as a simple operation like this ought to be?

```
(defn setpxl [^BufferedImage image data]
  (let [h (.getHeight image)
    w (.getWidth image)]
  (.setRGB image 0 0 w h ^ints data 0 w)
) )

(defn getrgb [rgb]
 (let [r  (bit-shift-right (bit-and rgb (int 0x00FF0000)) 16)
    g  (bit-shift-right (bit-and rgb (int 0x0000FF00)) 8)
    b  (bit-and rgb (int 0x000000FF))]
[r g b])
)

(defn graycalc [[r g b]]
  (let [gray (int (/ (+ r g b) 3))
    r  (bit-shift-left gray 16)
    g  (bit-shift-left gray 8)
    b  gray
    a  (bit-shift-left 0x00 24)
    ]
  (int (bit-or a r g b))))

(defn testrgb []
  (let [img (time (javax.imageio.ImageIO/read (as-file "D:/cat.jpg")))
    h (.getHeight img)
    w (.getWidth img)
    arr (time (int-array (getpxl img)))
    gray (time
          ;;why is amap so slow?

          ;;400ms
          (int-array (map #(graycalc (getrgb %1)) arr))

          ;;8000ms
          ;; (amap ^ints arr idx ret (graycalc (getrgb (aget ^ints arr idx))))
          )

    frame (JFrame. "grayscale image")
    label (JLabel. (ImageIcon. img))
    panel (.getContentPane frame)]

(-> panel (.add label))
(.setSize frame w h)
(.setVisible frame true)

(time (setpxl img gray))
(.repaint panel)
)
```

)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add bits and pieces of code to run your sample, so here is the resulting [gist](https://gist.github.com/hellonico/6848079) to start with.

Somehow I felt reflection was kicking in, since aget needs a bit of help with types to get to full speed. Here's a related [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133094/clojure-why-is-aget-so-slow).

Using:

```
 (set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
```

Was returning:

```
 Reflection warning, core.clj:46:11 - call to aset can't be resolved.
```

when loading the file.

Turns out, the function used on each pixel was missing a return type. We can add the type to your code by turning:

```
 (amap ^ints arr idx ret (graycalc (getrgb (aget ^ints arr idx))))
```

into:

```
 (amap ^ints arr idx ret ^int (graycalc (getrgb (aget ^ints arr idx))))
```

aset is used on each value of the array, so without type hint, the call was making use of reflection on each value of the array.

And the speed run turns into:

```
 imaging.core=> (load-file "src/imaging/core.clj")
 Reflection warning, core.clj:45:11 - call to  aset can't be resolved.
 #'imaging.core/testrgb
 imaging.core=> (testrgb)
 "Elapsed time: 107.138 msecs"
 "Elapsed time: 359.448 msecs"
 "Elapsed time: 44267.634 msecs"
 "Elapsed time: 92.022 msecs"
 nil
 imaging.core=> (load-file "src/imaging/core.clj")
 #'imaging.core/testrgb
 imaging.core=> (testrgb)
 "Elapsed time: 102.871 msecs"
 "Elapsed time: 423.294 msecs"
 "Elapsed time: 1377.818 msecs"
 "Elapsed time: 88.026 msecs"
```

For speed reference, map is running at:

```
 "Elapsed time: 2903.577 msecs"
```

and pmap at:

```
 "Elapsed time: 9351.502 msecs"
```

Comment: Can you type hint `graycalc`'s return value for the same effect?

Comment: Yes, that works too:

     (defn ^Integer graycalc [[r g b]] ...)

Comment: Genius!

Adding the type hinting to the output of the function makes amap run at the same speed as the normal map version. I suppose the map version is super optimized, or perhaps autoboxing is less of a performance hit than I thought it'd be...

Comment: Ah, so the difference I can see now is that I don't need to warm up the jit in order to make amap fast.