# Why is this Clojure micro benchmark so slow?

Tags: performance, clojure

[There was a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25005429/549617) which was answered successfully on comparing speeds of Clojure to Scala, but applying those same techniques to the following code still leaves it over 25 times slower than equivalent Scala code.  This is comparing Clojure 1.6.0 with Leiningen 2.5.0 on Java 1.8.0_40 to Scala 2.11.6:

The comparisons are made not using the REPL but using the Leiningen "run" command and run at about the same speed when run directly from java after producing a standalone '.jar' file using the Leiningen "uberjar" command.

The micro benchmark tests the speed of doing bit manipulations inside an array, which is typical of some low level types of tasks such as encryption or compression or in primes sieving.  To get a reasonable measurement interval and to avoid JIT overheads spoiling the results, the benchmark runs the same loop 1000 times.

The Clojure code is as follows:

```
(ns test-cljr-speed.core
  (:gen-class))

(set! *unchecked-math* true)

(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)

(defn testspeed
  "test array bit manipulating tight loop speeds."
  []
  (let [lps 1000,
        len (bit-shift-left 1 12),
        bits ^int (int (bit-shift-left 1 17))]
    (let [buf ^ints(int-array len)]
      (letfn [(doit []
                (loop [i ^int (int 0)]
                  (if (< i bits)
                    (let [w ^int (int (bit-shift-right i 5))]
                      (do
                        (aset-int ^ints buf w ^int (int (bit-or ^int (aget ^ints buf w)
                                                                ^long (bit-shift-left 1 ^long (bit-and i 31)))))
                        (recur (inc i)))))))]
        (dorun lps (repeatedly doit))))))

(defn -main
  "runs test."
  [& args]
  (let [strt (System/nanoTime),
        cnt (testspeed),
        stop (System/nanoTime)]
    (println "Took " (long (/ (- stop strt) 1000000)) " milliseconds.")))
```

Which produces the following output:

```
Took  9342  milliseconds.
```

I believe the problem to be related to reflection accessing the buffer array, but have applied all sorts of type hints as recommended and can't seem to find it.

Comparable Scala code is as follows:

```
object Main extends App {
  def testspeed() = {
    val lps = 1000
    val len = 1 << 12
    val bits = 1 << 17
    val buf = new Array[Int](len)
    def doit() = {
      def set1(i: Int): Unit =
        if (i < bits) {
          buf(i >> 5) |= 1 << (i & 31)
          set1(i + 1)
        }
      set1(0)
    }
    (0 until lps).foreach { _ => doit() }
  }

  val strt = System.nanoTime()
  val cnt = testspeed()
  val stop = System.nanoTime()
  println(s"Took ${(stop - strt) / 1000000} milliseconds.")
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
Took 365 milliseconds.
```

Doing the same job, it is over 25 times as fast!!!

I have turned on the *warn-on-reflection* flag and there doesn't seem to be any Java reflection going on where more hinting would help.  Perhaps I am not turning on some optimization settings properly (perhaps set in the project file for Leiningen?) as they are hard to dig out on the Internet; for Scala I have turned off all debugging output and enabled the compiler "optimize" flag, which makes some improvement.

My question is "**Is there something that can be done for this type of application that will make Clojure run at a speed more comparable to the Scala speed?**".

To short circuit any false speculation, yes, the array is indeed being filled with all binary ones a multiple of times as determined by another series of tests, and no, Scala is not optimizing away all but one loop.

I am not interested in discussions on the comparative merits of the two languages, but only how one can produce reasonably elegant Clojure code to do the same job at least ten times faster on a bit by bit basis (not a simple array fill operation, as the linear fill is just representative of more complex tasks such as prime number culling).

Using a Java BitSet does not have the problem (but not all algorithms are suited to only an set of booleans), nor likely does using a Java Integer array and Java class methods to access it, but one should be able to use the Clojure "native" array types without these sort of performance problems.

Comment: Some considerations: you provide type hints in some places in the Clojure code where they are definitely not needed (eg. the result of `int` is always int). Intermediate values and locals that are already bound do not need type hints if hinted at the point of binding. You use numeric literals in both programs, but in Scala they are integers, in Clojure they are longs. Just a style thing: Clojure's `let` is like `let*` in other lisps, and you don't need a nested let block in order to refer to prior bindings.

Comment: Also, for all your zeal with type hinting and coercing functions that couldn't return any other type, you are missing coercions where they are needed: `(type (inc (int 1))) => java.lang.Long`

Comment: @noisesmith, I'm obviously no expert with Clojure and was just throwing type hints at the problem willy-nilly hoping the slowness would go away.  I'll edit your suggestions into the answer code if it reduces the execution time and remove the type hints if they don't seem to make a change.  I was aware that numeric integer literals  were all longs and didn't worry about it as long calculations don't take longer than int ones on a 64 bit machine, but specified Int for Scala variables used as indexes as they use the Java limitation that array indices must be Int.  Thanks for pointing these out.

Comment: Clojure also uses the Java limitation that array indexes must be int, and it implicitly does that conversion (a relatively cheap one).

Comment: @noisesmith, yes, I think that letting the Clojure compiler decide when to do the int conversion to  rather than forcing it with an explicit coercion is likely slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your type hints are not affecting the execution time of the Clojure code, and on my machine the updated version is not an improvement:

```
user=> (time (testspeed))
"Elapsed time: 6256.075155 msecs"
nil
user=> (time (testspeedx))
"Elapsed time: 6371.968782 msecs"
nil
```

You are doing a number of type hints that are not needed, and stripping them all away actually makes the code faster:

```
(defn testspeed-unhinted
  "test array bit manipulating tight loop speeds."
  []
  (let [lps 1000,
        len (bit-shift-left 1 12),
        bits (bit-shift-left 1 17)]
    (let [buf (int-array len)]
      (letfn [(doit []
                (loop [i (int 0)]
                  (if (< i bits)
                    (let [w (bit-shift-right i 5)]
                      (do
                        (aset buf w (bit-or (aget buf w)
                                            (bit-shift-left 1 (bit-and i 31))))
                        (recur (inc i)))))))]
        (dorun lps (repeatedly doit)))))))

user=> (time (testspeed-unhinted))
"Elapsed time: 270.652953 msecs"
```

It occurred to me that coercing `i` to int on the recur would potentially speed up the code, but it actually slows it down. With that in mind, I decided to try removing `int`s from the code entirely and see what the result was performance wise:

```
 (defn testspeed-unhinted-longs
   "test array bit manipulating tight loop speeds."
   []
   (let [lps 1000,
         len (bit-shift-left 1 12),
         bits (bit-shift-left 1 17)]
     (let [buf (long-array len)]
       (letfn [(doit []
                 (loop [i 0]
                   (if (< i bits)
                     (let [w (bit-shift-right i 5)]
                       (do
                         (aset buf w (bit-or (aget buf w)
                                             (bit-shift-left 1 (bit-and i 31))))
                         (recur (inc i)))))))]
         (dorun lps (repeatedly doit)))))))
user=> (time (testspeed-unhinted-longs))
"Elapsed time: 221.025048 msecs"
```

The performance gain was relatively small, so I used the `criterium` lib to get accurate microbenchmarks for the difference:

```
user=> (crit/bench (testspeed-unhinted))
WARNING: Final GC required 2.2835076167941852 % of runtime
Evaluation count : 240 in 60 samples of 4 calls.
             Execution time mean : 260.877321 ms
    Execution time std-deviation : 18.168141 ms
   Execution time lower quantile : 251.952111 ms ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 321.995872 ms (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 15.568045 ns

Found 8 outliers in 60 samples (13.3333 %)
    low-severe   1 (1.6667 %)
    low-mild     7 (11.6667 %)
 Variance from outliers : 51.8061 % Variance is severely inflated by outliers
nil
user=> (crit/bench (testspeed-unhinted-longs))
Evaluation count : 300 in 60 samples of 5 calls.
             Execution time mean : 232.078704 ms
    Execution time std-deviation : 24.828378 ms
   Execution time lower quantile : 219.615718 ms ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 297.456135 ms (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 15.568045 ns

Found 11 outliers in 60 samples (18.3333 %)
    low-severe   2 (3.3333 %)
    low-mild     9 (15.0000 %)
 Variance from outliers : 72.1097 % Variance is severely inflated by outliers
nil
```

So the final result is, you can get a huge speedup by removing your type hints (since everything critical in the code is already totally unambiguous type wise), and you can get a small improvement on top of that by switching from `int` to `long` (at least on my 64 bit intel machine).

Comment: It looks like the problem I've been fighting was entirely due to the performance bug with "aset-int", which no type hinting helps, as when I strip all type hints as per your code but use "aset-int" instead of "aset" (along with the one required forced coercion to int), the performance returns to as it was before - terrible.  I'm on 64 bit AMD Bulldozer, and the run speeds are 2X as slow due to the L1 cache bottleneck.  Using long's on a 32-bit machine is likely slower due to having to simulate 64-bit ops using 32-bit regs.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Using a "long-array" as you have above means one needs to adjust some shifts, as in making the shift 11 when defining "len" (to keep the array the same size in bytes), the right shift to 6 from 5, and "& 63" instead of "& 31" for the other left shift, else half of the array buffer is not being used.  On my machine, Scala is faster using an array of int's but Clojure is faster using an array of long's (each of the same size in bytes) - likely due to the "native" primitive type each uses by default.  Thanks for pointing to the criterium lib; didn't know about it.

Comment: In editing my answer, I see why there was no improvement after the last edit:  I edited in a different trial version rather than the one reflecting your suggestions, so it's little wonder that your first comparison still has the performance problem:  that time I was using "aset-boolean" which still has this performance bug. The new version has slight improvements to what you have suggested above as to the size of the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just answer my own question to help others that may be fighting this same issue:

After perusing [another question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10133323/549617), I accidentally stumbled on the problem:  "aset" is fine; "aset-int" (and all the other specialized forms of "aset-?") is not and no amount of type hinting helps.

In the following code for the test procedure **Edited as per @noisesmith's answer**, all I change is to using "long-array" ("int array" also works, just not quite as fast) and use the "aset" instead of "aset-long" (or "aset-int" for "int-array") and have eliminated all type hints:

```
(set! *unchecked-math* true)

(defn testspeed
  "test array bit manipulating tight loop speeds."
  []
  (let [lps 1000,
        len (bit-shift-left 1 11),
        bits (bit-shift-left 1 17),
        buf (long-array len)]
    (letfn [(doit []
              (loop [i (int 0)]
                (if (< i bits)
                  (let [w (bit-shift-right i 6)]
                    (do
                      (aset buf w (bit-or (aget buf w)
                                          (bit-shift-left 1 (bit-and i 63))))
                      (recur (inc i)))))))]
      (dorun lps (repeatedly doit)))))
```

With the result that it produces the following output:

```
Took  395  milliseconds.
```

With "aset-long" instead of "aset", the output is:

```
Took  7424  milliseconds.
```

for a speed-up of almost 19 times.

Now this is just very slightly slower than the Scala code using a Int array (which is faster for Scala than using a Long array), but that is somewhat understandable as Clojure does not have the read/modify/write primitives as "|=" and it seems that the compiler is not smart enough to see that a read/modify/write operation is what is implied in the above code.

However, being only a few percent slower is completely acceptable and means that for this type of application, performance is not the criteria for choosing between Scala or Clojure.

This solution doesn't make sense, as the specialized versions of "aset-?" should really just be calling through to the overloaded cases of "aset", but it seems there is a problem/bug affecting their performance, at least with the current version 1.6.0.

Comment: This gives me: `IllegalArgumentException Value out of range for int: 4294967295  clojure.lang.RT.intCast`

Comment: @noisesmith, you need the "(set! unchecked-math true)" from the question code; this is just modified code as to the "testspeed" procedure. I'll edit it if there are any speed differences in the real coersions necessary as per your comments in the question